# strtotime is not working proper in php for future date?

Tags: php, date, date-conversion

When i am converting date from d-m-Y in Y-m-d format. i am facing some issues for it.

example 19/08/1989 will convert into 1989/08/19 (it's correct),

19/08/2059 will convert into  1970/01/01 (it's not correct)

```
$re_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['re_date']));
```

Help me please. thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the value of $_POST['re_date']

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum date allowed is Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC on 32 bit system

From the [strotime docs](https://www.php.net/strtotime):

> **Note:**
>
> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
> 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC.

If you want it to work for 32 bit system then try like this using `DateTime`:

```
$date = new DateTime($_POST['re_date']);
    
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: You should specify that it's only for 32bit systems

Comment: Why catch an exception just to `exit`? Simply *don't* catch the exception for the same effect.

Comment: @deceze:- I was focussing more on DateTime! :)

Comment: All the more reason not to propagate bad error handling practices in sample code... :) +1 BTW.

Comment: @deceze:- Yes I will take care of that. Thanks!

Comment: also, strtotime does not work for past date beyond 1970-01-01. it returns false.

Answer (score 2):

better trick

```
$str=explode('/',$_POST['re_date']);

$newdate = $str[2].'/'.$str[1].'/'.$str[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

$re_date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['re_date']));

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = $_POST['re_date'];
$date = str_replace("/", "-", $date);
$re_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```